# Cómo puedo excluir el paquete @angular/cli del proceso de npm-install durante la construcción de una imagen de Docker?

Tags: angularjs, npm, docker, angular-cli

Estoy empezando un projecto que hará uso de **Angular.js** y **Node.js** y estarán contenidos en una imagen de Docker. En mi `Dockerfile` he indicado que Docker debe ejecutar la instrucción `RUN npm install` para configurar mi projecto cuando se Docker construya la imagen. Esta es una parte de los registros de construcción de la imagen:

```
Step 4/10 : RUN npm install
---> Running in 90d567c905d4

> @angular/cli@6.0.3 postinstall /usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular/cli
> node ./bin/ng-update-message.js

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})    

added 295 packages in 12.979s
```

He instalado el paquete`@angular/cli` con **npm** en mi Sistema Operativo y no quiero que el paquete `@angular/cli` se instale en mi projecto cuando Docker ejecute `RUN npm install`, eso hace más pesada mi imagen.

**Cómo puedo excluir el paquete `@angular/cli` del proceso de `npm-install` durante la construcción de una imagen de Docker?**

Para intentar resolverlo uso esta instrucción en mi `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN npm uninstall @angular/cli
```

Pero no resuelve mi problema. Que me sugieren?

Answer (score 1):

La única forma de que no instale un paquete con el comando `npm install` es que éste no se encuentre en el archivo `package.json` o que el paquete se especifique como una dependencia `dev` y se instale los paquetes de producción. Si el objetivo es implementar el despliegue mediante docker crearía un `docker swarm` en el cual en un contenedor estaría el backend (NodeJS) y en el otro contenedor se encontraría una imagen de NGINX con la solución de angular. Igualmente podrían estar contenido los dos en el mismo contenedor pero aconsejo separar el proyecto en dos, uno que contenga Angular y otro que contenga NodeJS.